# Node.js : sharing variables between modules via module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a variable that i want to share it between modules and add to it,remove from it and modify it in a Node.js program here is what i did:

shared_storage.js

```
var locations = {};
locations['Brandenburg Gate'] = {latitude: 52.516272, longitude: 13.377722};
locations['Dortmund U-Tower'] = {latitude: 51.515, longitude: 7.453619};

module.exports = locations;


var state = new Object();   // Create the object
state.ready = "r";
state.offline = "o";
state.loaded = "l";


var location_stats = {};

location_stats ['Brandenburg Gate'] = state.ready;
location_stats ['Dortmund U-Tower'] = state.loaded;

module.exports = location_stats ;
```

mymodule.js

```
var spots= require('./shared_storage').locations;
console.log(spots);
```

but the result is:

> undefined

where is the item that i add to the variable in the `shared_storage.js` ?

Comment: Can you please post your full shared_storage.js? whether you created constructor? if yes u have export the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **this** 
`var spots= require('./shared_storage').locations;`

To **this**

`var spots= require('./shared_storage')`

The reason is you are exporting object as a module, so you don't need to access modules property, because it does not have any **own** property :)

Now that is fixed, you need to reconsider your implementation. Sharing state across modules via another module is simple but not good. For couple of reasons:

1. Server crash/restart
2. Multiple instance service
3. It is a dirty approach (memory leak, difficult abstraction etc.)

Better and simplest approach would be to store those in the database